# Get SCSI id for CD-R for red hat linux

Tags: linux, ksh, redhat, scsi

I want to get the SCSI ID of the CD-R /CD-ROM using the command.As well as I want to check that scsi board is installed properly or not on the system using command in korn shell script.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 14 system, the following command prints the CD-ROM entry that's in /proc/scsi/scsi:

> `grep -B2 CD /proc/scsi/scsi`

That is, on my system it prints

```
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATAPI    Model: iHAS124   B      Rev: AL0H
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

If what you want is the string *scsi1*, use awk, cut, grep, sed, perl, or whatever to isolate it out.  For example (where bash prompt is `>`):

```
> CDID=$(grep -B2 CD-R /proc/scsi/scsi |head -1|cut -d' ' -f2)
> echo $CDID
scsi1
```

or

```
> CDID=$(grep -B2 CD-R /proc/scsi/scsi |egrep -o scsi.)
> echo $CDID
scsi1
```

You can find out CD drive model names and serial numbers from `udisks` output.  Eg:

```
> for i in /dev/sr?; do echo $i $(udisks --show-info $i |egrep 'model:|serial:'); done  
/dev/sr0 model: ATAPI iHAS124 B serial: 6543210_567895501234
```

Comment: What Red Hat release are you running?  What kernel #?  Eg, what is output from `uname -a` and from `cat /etc/issue.net` ?  Also see [linux rescan scsi bus](http://thornelabs.net/2012/08/22/linux-rescan-scsi-bus.html)